# fetch_assoc() loop HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, sql

Can't find a way to fetch my results, sql request is good but it keeps crashing (HTTP ERROR 500) when using this code with the while loop.

I don't have any problem when using `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` but I have to loop to update every records.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE statut = '1' AND NOW() BETWEEN dateAller AND dateRetour"; // requete sql sur les réservations validées dont la tranche horaire est en cours de validité
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sql = "UPDATE vehicules SET statut = '2' WHERE immat = '$row[immat]'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: check for Errors after executing SQL statements

Comment: You verride your result in the Loop: ` $result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: @Jens i don't get any special error, or server doesn't seems to display them

Comment: you never ask the Server so you can not see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you override `$result` in your Loop, so `->fetch_assoc()` will be called on the result of the `update` Statement in the second iteration. You have to change to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE statut = '1' AND NOW() BETWEEN dateAller AND dateRetour"; // requete sql sur les réservations validées dont la tranche horaire est en cours de validité
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sql = "UPDATE vehicules SET statut = '2' WHERE immat = '$row[immat]'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: So obvious now... Of course i was overwriting on $result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
$sql = "UPDATE vehicules SET statut = '2' WHERE immat = '$row[immat]'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE vehicules SET statut = '2' WHERE immat = '".$row['immat']."'";
$conn->query($sql);
```

You are overwriting `$result` with the result of the update query. You probably don't need this result (at least you are not using it yet), so you can easily remove the assignment.

Additionally you need `'` or `"` to access an array (`$row`) by a key.
In your case you are lucky and it works without quotes.
Explanation:

PHP sees a constant called `immat`. If the constant is defined, the value is returned, it isn't defined, PHP falls back to the string `"immat"`.

Anyway it's always a better practice to use quotes!

Comment: He's reading the value from his own database, so it should be prepared already I guess?

Comment: *Change these lines* is not an answer. *Change these lines ... because. ..* is an answer. You should explain why, so it will help OP and otheer Readers, what the Problem is

Comment: I added a small explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE statut = '1' AND NOW() BETWEEN dateAller AND dateRetour";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $immat = $row["immat"];
        $sql = "UPDATE vehicules SET statut = '2' WHERE immat = '$immat'";
        $updateResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }
}
?>
```